# Adding a Spec (profile) to a current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello Stackoverflow programmer's,

I'm currently running a small side-project next to my school's project but i'm quite stuck for a while now.

*Here's my problem:* I have a user with some standerd attributes and that user has_one :spec. A spec is sort of an extended version for a profile.
Now this spec has as i mentioned some extra attributes, but i can't seem to assign it correctly to the current user. The strange thing is i am able to make a spec in the console.

Here's my Spec_controller:

```
class SpecController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # redirect_to :controller => "user", :action => "index"
    # @user.spec = @spec.new
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @spec.user_id = current_user.id
    @spec = current_user.spec(spec_params)
    @spec = Spec.find(params[:id])
      if @spec.update(params.require(:spec).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :gender, :birthdate, :occupation, :city, :state))
        flash[:notice] = "Changes saved."
        redirect_to users_path
      else
        flash[:notice] = "er ging iets mis!"
        render 'edit'
      end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])  
    @spec = Spec.new
  end

  def new
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @spec = Spec.new
  end

private

  def spec_params
    params.require(:spec).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :gender, :birthdate, :occupation, :city, :state)
  end

   def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:screen_name, :email, :password)
  end


end
```

The Spec model:

```
class Spec < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    ALL_FIELDS = %w(first_name last_name occupation gender birthdate city state zip_code)
    STRING_FIELDS = %w(first_name last_name occupation city state)
    VALID_GENDERS = ["Male", "Female"]
    START_YEAR = 1900
    VALID_DATES = DateTime.new(START_YEAR)..DateTime.now

    validates_inclusion_of :gender, in: VALID_GENDERS, allow_nill: false, message: "Must be male or female"
    validates_inclusion_of :birthdate, in: VALID_DATES, allow_nill: false, message: "Is invalid"

end
```

The user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :spec

    validates_presence_of :email, :screen_name
    validates_uniqueness_of :email, :screen_name
    has_secure_password 

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :screen_name, use: :slugged

end
```

And the edit view in case if it's needed:

```
<%= form_for :spec do |form| %>
<fieldset>
    <legend><%= @title %></legend>
    <%= text_field_tag form, "first_name" %>
    <%= text_field_tag form, "last_name" %>
    <div class="form_row">
        <label for="gender">Gender:</label><br>
        <%= radio_button :spec, :gender, "Male"  %> Male
        <%= radio_button :spec, :gender, "Female" %> Female
    </div>
    <div class="form_row">
        <label for="birthdate">Birthdate:</label><br>
    <%= date_select :spec, :birthdate, :start_year => Spec::START_YEAR, :end_year => Time.now.year, :include_blank => true, :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>
    </div>
    <%= text_field_tag form, "occupation" %>
    <%= text_field_tag form, "city" %>
    <%= text_field_tag form, "state" %>
    </br>
    <%= submit_tag "Update", :class => "submit", :controller => :spec, :action => :update %>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources 'spec'
  #post ':controller(/:spec(/:id(.:edit)))'

  get 'spec/index'

  get 'spec/edit'

  get 'profile/index'

  get 'profile/show'

  get 'profile/:screen_name', controller: 'profile', action: 'show'

 resources :users, only: [:index, :new, :create, :login, :destroy, :edit, :show, :update]

controller :sessions do
     get :login, to: 'sessions#new'
     delete :logout, to: 'sessions#destroy'
     post :authenticate, to: 'sessions#create'

end

    root 'site#index'

    get 'site/index'

    get 'site/about'

    get 'site/help'

  end
```

I hope my code is readable, still trying to figure out alot of stuff inside of rails (first programming language).

Thanks!

Comment: why you have used code below redirect method in index  user.spec = spec.new inside indix also why you are not using spec_params method inside uodate method also when you have current_user then why you are finding user with session id . Please update your code. You can also check what parameter is coming inside update method and if you are getting any error paste that

Comment: Thankyou for your fast responce Arv, ive submutted a few changes in the Spec controller. The redirect and spec.new inside the index method were indeed a mistake, probably a copy-error. But still i'm getting no progress yet, strange thing is when i put let's say 'puts "something"' above in the update method to see if my server log does anything special but i'm not even finding the puts in the log, like it doesn't even find the whole update method.

Comment: It's pretty pointless asking people to debug code that is different from what you're actually running. In any case the form would probably submit to the create action, not the update one.

Comment: Yea but still i thought to give it a shot, currently in my form i have under the submit button: "<%= submit_tag "Update", controller: "spec", action: "create" %>" so i assume it uses the right def.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly got it to work! Ive made a new def in Spec controller instead of update i made a create function. Kinda strange in the first place why i made it a update function when you want to create a complete new Spec!

Thanks alot for your help :) much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
@spec = current_user.spec
if @spec.update(spec_params)
...
```

Update:
I think the link to update spec will be something like this `/specs/1/edit`, getting and updating spec should be

```
@spec = Spec.find(params[:id])
if @spec.update(spec_params)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for you're responce Johnny, ive tried that but still no progress :(

Comment: Please post the err msg if any

Comment: I'm not receiving any error message's, just the render form that i assigned in def update.

Comment: @Johnny Dương, thanks again for the responce, i have a feeling we're getting there!, i think the error now is in my routes file (it's a big mess so you don't have to try to find the bug there haha) Just getting the error 'No route matches [POST] "/spec/33/edit"' So you were right about the update spec link( /specs/1/edit. Ive uploaded my routes file above.

Comment: `/spec/33/edit` used to display the form, and the form should submit to `spec/33` with `POST` method, I think you should try change your view a little (use `form_for(@spec)...`)

Comment: Teacher advised me today to drop my current database and give all the attributes that i have for the user in the spec model to the user model itself. Not really the best advise i'd say. Currently recieving some strange error "<%= form_for(@spec) do |form| %>"; undefined method `specs_path' for... in Spec#edit (updated the controller Spec)

Comment: nothing strange here, try remove `get 'spec/index' and get 'spec/edit'` in your routes